# Why does maximising the screen of the browser mess up the dot graph in a quarto file?

Tags: dot, quarto, reveal.js

I am using `dot` language in a `quarto` `revealjs` presentation to produce a figure:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
---


## Dot

```{dot}
digraph {
        
        graph [layout = dot, rankdir = LR]
        
        node [shape = rectangle, style = filled, fillcolor = Linen]
        
        # input
        meteo [label = "Input1"]
        static [label = "Input2"]
        
        # nn
        lstm [label = "Model1", shape = box3d, fillcolor = pink]
        fc1 [label = "Model2", shape = box3d, fillcolor = pink]
        fc2 [label = "Model3", shape = box3d, fillcolor = pink]
        
        # physics
        physics [label = "Model4", shape = box3d, fillcolor = lightblue]
        
        # output
        preds_nn [label = "Out", fillcolor = lightgreen]
        preds_hybrid [label = "Out2", fillcolor = lightgreen]
        static_output [label = "Out3", fillcolor = lightgreen]
        
        # beta
        beta [label = "Input3", fillcolor = lightgreen]
        
        # observations
        obs [label = "Y"]
        
        # graph
        {meteo static} -> lstm -> fc1 -> preds_nn -> physics -> preds_hybrid -> obs
        meteo -> physics
        obs -> preds_hybrid
        
        beta -> physics
        static -> fc2 -> static_output -> physics
        
        }
```
````

When I render the file and open using a browser, I get this:

[image]

It looks as expected. However, when I maximise the screen of the browser pressing F4 on a Mac keyboard, I get this:

[image]

Why are the texts on the figure messed up and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Although not a solution, you can do a page refresh after going to fullscreen mode so that the text position gets recalculated (or even better, you can write up a quick javascript snippet that listens for fullscreen change or `F4` button keydown and do a page refresh for yourself.